# Prevent checkbox from unchecking when clicked (without disable or readonly)

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, checkbox

I'm using a checkbox and I want people to be able to check/uncheck it.
However, when they uncheck it, I'm using a jQueryUI modal popup to confirm that they really want to do that. Thus they can click <kbd>OK</kbd> or <kbd>Cancel</kbd>, and I want my checkbox to be unchecked only if they click <kbd>OK</kbd>.
That's why I would like to catch the uncheck event to prevent the checkbox from being visually unchecked, and uncheck it myself programmatically if the user happens to click on <kbd>OK</kbd>.

How could I do that ?

PS: I know I could re-check it after if the user clicks on <kbd>Cancel</kbd> but that would trigger the `check` event which I do not want.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

```
$("#checkboxID").on("click", function (e) {
    var checkbox = $(this);
    if (checkbox.is(":checked")) {
        // do the confirmation thing here
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: I think this answer may be doing the opposite of what the asker wanted. Implementing it prevented me from checking boxes, not from unchecking them. I added the "!" to the if condition though and all was well.

Comment: Yeah this does the opposite of preventing a checkbox from being unchecked

Answer (score 16):

Pure CSS Solution

Select Checkbox like -

```
input[type="checkbox"] {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

Works Pretty well, and now you can toggle your checkbox on any element click of your choice.

Comment: This is a very simplistic solution +1

Comment: This is very neat, but it fails when you have a label that points to it, as it bypasses this.

Comment: @PaulG. I think you can add the selector of the label to use same css property

Comment: Very simplistic. Thanls

Answer (score 13):

Something like:

```
$("#test").on('change', function() {
    this.checked=!this.checked?!confirm('Really uncheck this one ?'):true;
});
​
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/4gAH7/3/)

Comment: +1 nice. You can make that even shorter/clearer too: `this.checked = this.checked || !confirm('Really uncheck this one ?');`

Comment: I was totally wrong but I cannot change my downvote anymore, sorry

Answer (score 3):

How about using the HTML disabled property?

```
<input type="checkbox" name="my_name" value="my_value" disabled> My value<br>
```

Link:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/disabled

Comment: this is the most efficient way of ensuring the checkbox is not unchecked as it does not reply on any javascript. If you don't need to run javascript then don't. Save on processing power and keep javascript file sizes small for fast page delivery.

Comment: although I'm using this reference, but the title says without readonly or disable

Answer (score 2):

```
   $("#checkboxID").click(function(e) { 
      var checkbox = $(this);
      if (checkbox.is(":checked")) {
       //check it 
      } else {
       // prevent from being unchecked
        this.checked=!this.checked;
      }
   });
```

Comment: Your answer's code is formatted badly and some comments or explanations will surely be helpful

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#yourCheckBoxId").on('change',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#yourPopDiv").popup();
});
```

`preventDefault()` will disable default behavior of your `input[type="checkbox"]`

And on your popup div

```
$("#ok").on('click',function(){
    $("#yourCheckBoxId").attr("checked",true);
});
```

Comment: If there are any odd UI overlays, the OP can also use stopPropagation() to prevent it. I know jQuery UI has weird overlays to control the main checkbox... so that sometimes has helped me :)

Answer (score 0):

My value

Light javascript. Better than disable if you still need the element submitted in a form.