# javascript click event on checkbox causes checkbox to be unchecked

Tags: jquery, asp.net, checkbox, webforms

Hi and thanks in advance for any advice you can give me.

I have a page that has a gridview with a checkbox in a HeaderTemplate and checkboxes in the columns below. All the checkboxes not in the HeaderTemplate have a class of 'selectCB'. I created the following click event in document.ready so that the checkbox in the header could serve the purpose of a check all/ uncheck all function. While the checkboxes are being all checked the Check All checkbox itself is being unchecked every time so the reverse procedure of unchecking all can never be completed.

I've checked out a number of posts on SO, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19484140/is-it-possible-to-change-checkbox-state-without-causing-click-event) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12138821/prevent-checkbox-from-unchecking-when-clicked-without-disable-or-readonly) are some examples but nothing has worked so far. The page is using jquery 1.6.1 for now so I'm limited to those options until a future upgrade takes place.

Here is the click function:

```
    $('#cbAll').click(function() {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    if ($('#cbAll').is(':checked')) {
        $('#gvCheckbox').find('td:first-child input[type="checkbox"]').each(function() {
            var cb = $(this);
            cb.attr('checked', true);
        });
        $(this).attr('checked', true);
    } else {
        $('#gvCheckbox').find('td:first-child input[type="checkbox"]').each(function() {
            var cb = $(this);
            cb.attr('checked', false);
        });
        $(this).attr('checked', false);
    }
    return false;
});
```

This is the Header and column from the gridview:

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left"></HeaderStyle>
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <input type="checkbox" id="cbAll" clientidmode="Static" />
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <input type="checkbox" id="cbOne" clientidmode="Static" CssClass="selectCB" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

When I go through this code using Chrome's debugger, I don't see any errors and its not until it finishes processing the code that the check box becomes unchecked. I've tried using .live instead and it has the same results. What else can I try? Or could someone help figure out how to more effectively debug this issue to find the problem?

Comment: You're forgetting to pass the event as a parameter on the click handler. $('#cbAll').click(function(event)

Comment: Post the whole markup or link to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `change` instead of `click`, don't change the checked property in the handler, use `prop` instead of `attr`, and add a parameter for the event object. I've also simplified the function significantly.

```
$('#cbAll').change(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();

    $('#gvCheckbox')
        .find('td:first-child input[type="checkbox"]')
        .prop('checked', this.checked);
});
```

Comment: It certainly is a lot cleaner but unfortunately the check box in the header template is still being unchecked. The other check boxes are being checked correctly.

Comment: Seems to work for me: http://jsfiddle.net/25ESy/. Can you reproduce the issue in a fiddle?

Comment: I've found the problem, in another section there is a .tablesorter being applied to the gridview and that is what is causing the checkbox to be unchecked. I think I should be able to filter that column out using .tablesorter settings but because this answer does clean up the code and it functions better now I'm going to mark it as the correct answer.

Comment: Follow up for any one interested the tablesorter solution was this: $('.tableSort').tablesorter({ headers: { 0: { sorter: false } } });

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need `event.preventDefault()` and `return false;`?

**[event.preventDefault()]:** If this method is called, the default action of the event will not be triggered.

**[return false;]:** Performs three tasks when called:

1. event.preventDefault();
2. event.stopPropagation();
3. Stops callback execution and returns immediately when called.

If you just comment this two methods your code works. (PS: Use `.prop()` rather then `.attr()`):

```
$(document).on('click','#cbAll',function(event) {
    //event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    if ($('#cbAll').is(':checked')) {
        $('#gvCheckbox').find('td:first-child input[type="checkbox"]').each(function() {
            var cb = $(this);
            cb.prop('checked', true);
        });
        $(this).prop('checked', true);
    } else {
        $('#gvCheckbox').find('td:first-child input[type="checkbox"]').each(function() {
            var cb = $(this);
            cb.prop('checked', false);
        });
        $(this).prop('checked', false);
    }
    //return false;
});
```

Demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/cbQt4/1/

Comment: Although not in this sample, I did have return false and it did not work either. But I will try it again.